# How to get rid of "application downloaded from the internet" message when installing homebrew casks?

Tags: macos, homebrew

I used homebrew cask to install many applications for quite a while now. But recently macOS keeps asking me to first confirm the "application downloaded from the internet" question that is usually only displayed for apps that are run for the first time.

[image]

What happened and how can I get rid of this?

**Update**

I use an admin account to install apps (`brew cask install calibre`), but I basically use a non-admin account all the time. I can get rid of the message by logging into the admin account and launching the app once and then the message disappears also for the user account.

Comment: There is no need to link to the accepted answer in the question. If you want to explain why you moved the "accept" mark to another answer, a comment below the answer might be the better place (especially because the poster of that answer gets notified then).

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Wohoo! I just realized that there is apparently now a built-in solution to the problem! [Homebrew offers a `--no-quarantine` flag](https://github.com/Homebrew/brew/pull/4656). That means one can now install casks without the annoying message, by using

```
brew install --no-quarantine calibre
```

or

```
brew reinstall --no-quarantine calibre
```

**Update:** There is currently a [bug in Homebrew](https://github.com/Homebrew/brew/issues/9139) that prevents the latter command (`reinstall`) from working.

To make this a default option, add this to your profile:

```
echo 'export HOMEBREW_CASK_OPTS=--no-quarantine' >> ~/.profile
```

Comment: You may wish to put `export HOMEBREW_CASK_OPTS=--no-quarantine` in your `~/.profile`.

Answer (score 9):

As you mentioned in your update, you can open the application as an admin user. A more direct way is to run this command as an admin:

```
xattr -r -d com.apple.quarantine /Applications/Calibre.app
```

Comment: Accepting this answer because `sudo spctl --master-disable` of the other answer is potentially overkill. https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/337320/how-to-get-rid-of-application-downloaded-from-the-internet-message-when-instal#comment436213_337323

Comment: Sorry – un-accepting this answer. Although this is technically still the best answer, I found a [more "official" way](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/376476/45492) to do acheive what I want in Homebrew. As this question is specifically about Homebrew, it seems more applicable here.

Comment: @n1000 Good find, I upvoted your new answer because I constantly run into this.

Answer (score 3):

More of a workaround than a solution: Launching the App from an account with admin privileges once, makes the message disappear also for the non-admin account. Not sure if this is a bug or a feature... In the past it used to work like that also from non-admin accounts.

Answer (score 0):

You need to allow it, in the system preferences.

Open the Terminal app from the /Applications/Utilities/ folder and then enter the following command syntax:

```
sudo spctl --master-disable
```

Hit return and authenticate with an admin password

Relaunch System Preferences and go to “Security & Privacy” and the “General” tab

You will now see the “Anywhere” option under ‘Allow apps downloaded from:’ Gatekeeper options

[image]

Do not forget to change it back for your safety.

```
sudo spctl --master-enable
```

**Alternative method** is to remove the Apple imposed Quarantine using Terminal command.

For example, if all of the files are in ~/Downloads/ then you would use:

```
xattr -r -d com.apple.quarantine ~/Downloads/
```

Comment: Really? Do I need the big guns?! The app will start, it is just this annoying message every time. I think you may be confusing it with the message where macOS blocks the app from launching entirely. Strange it worked before. Did Apple change their policy with the last update or something?

Comment: Yes Apple changed the policy and actually removed the Anywhere.

Comment: It will mark the file as not secure download, and that is why you get the warning.

Comment: Unfortunately this does not work. I could change to "Anywhere" but the message persists. I did try: reboot, `brew cask reinstall typora`, change the settings in Security back and forth... No success :(

Comment: **Sorry** - my bad. My question did not mention a (maybe) important detail: I use a user account. Will update now.

Comment: Thanks! This almost seems a bug to me, because launching the App only once from the admin account gets rid of the message -- as I would expected and as it used to work on my non-admin account.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that `sudo spctl --master-disable` is only needed for apps that will not launch because they are from an unknown developer (and even in that case, it's more preferable to just right-click the app and choose `open` rather than disabling via spctl). In any event, it's unrelated to this specific dialog box.

Answer (score 0):

Export variable `HOMEBREW_CASK_OPTS` containing `--no-quarantine` and create a shell alias for user to run `brew` as `admin` account.

#### Fish

**config.fish**

```
set -x HOMEBREW_CASK_OPTS --no-quarantine
alias brew="sudo -HEu admin brew"
```

#### zsh

**.zprofile**

```shell
export HOMEBREW_CASK_OPTS="--no-quarantine"
alias brew='sudo -Hu admin /opt/homebrew/bin/brew'
```